# How to wikilink to a specific section?

Tags: wikipedia

This [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel_Knight) has the following [wikilink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Link#Wikilinks_(internal_links)):

```
[[Gabriel Knight: Sins of the Fathers|Gabriel Knight: Sins of the Fathers 20th Anniversary Edition]]
```

This wikilink points to the top of the [Gabriel Knight: Sins of the Fathers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel_Knight:_Sins_of_the_Fathers) article, but it would be more appropriate if it pointed to the section "20th Anniversary Edition" inside that article instead.

I know I can use the URL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel_Knight:_Sins_of_the_Fathers#20th_Anniversary_Edition to do that, but I want to keep the wikilink format.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just copy it from the URL:

```
[[Gabriel_Knight:_Sins_of_the_Fathers#20th_Anniversary_Edition|Gabriel Knight: Sins of the Fathers 20th Anniversary Edition]]
```

(Spaces instead of underscores would work too.)